# Why is java.lang.Integer ignored in auto Parcelable implementation by Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, parcelable

This is the automatic `Parcelable` implementation generated by Android Studio. It somehow, always ignores `resultCode` which is of type `Integer`

```
public class TestParceable implements Parcelable {

        private String message;
        private Integer resultCode; //an Integer   

    protected TestParceable(Parcel in) {
        message = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(message);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<TestParceable> CREATOR = new Creator<TestParceable>() {
        @Override
        public TestParceable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TestParceable(in);
        }

        @Override
        public TestParceable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TestParceable[size];
        }
    };
}
```

On the other hand, if I change the type of `resultCode` to `int`, the automatic `Parcelable` implementation considers it.

```
public class TestParceable implements Parcelable {

        private String message;
        private int resultCode; //an int

protected TestParceable(Parcel in) {
    message = in.readString();
    resultCode = in.readInt();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(message);
    dest.writeInt(resultCode);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<TestParceable> CREATOR = new Creator<TestParceable>() {
    @Override
    public TestParceable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new TestParceable(in);
    }

    @Override
    public TestParceable[] newArray(int size) {
        return new TestParceable[size];
    }
};
```

Am I missing something here or is this and Android Studio bug?

Comment: My guess is that it is an Android Studio bug, though I do not see an issue filed for it at the moment.

Comment: Last I checked Android Studio doesn't provide a Parcelable code generator and we had to use tools like https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin . Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm using AS 2.2.3

Comment: Me too. How did you generate this code?

Comment: @VeneetReddy When you add `implements Parcelable` to a class definition, AS suggests to provide an auto implementation via intentions. I used that to generate

Comment: Yep, seems to be a bug..

Comment: @CommonsWare I opened an issue here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233034) which is fixed for Studio 2.4.

Comment: @GoogleAndroidStudioTeamMember where is Android Studio 2.4? There is 3.0 still in preview due to Kotlin?